# Variables uninitialized in function

Tags: c, initialization

My task is to write a program that takes three inputs and gives back three values. The entirety of the program is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>


    int findPercent(int percent)
    {
    int p = percent / 100;
    return p;
    }

    double convertSquareYards(int a)
    {
    double sy = a * 4840;
    return sy;
    }

    double convertCubicYards(double sy, double i, int p)
    {
    double cy = (sy * p) * (i / 36);
    return cy;
    }

    double convertGallons(double cy)
    {
    double g = cy / 201.974026;
    return g;
    }

    double convertPounds(double g)
    {
    double lb = g / 8.3430;
    return lb;
    }

    double convertTonnes(double lb)
    {
    double t = lb / 2000;
    return t;
    }

    double convertCubicFeet(double cy)
    {
    double cf = cy * 27;
    return cf;
    }

    double findHeight(double cf)
    {
    double h = ((cf / (360 * 160)) / 5280);
    return h;
    }

    int main(void)
    {

    double g, t, h, lb, i, cy, a, percent, cf;

    printf("What is the size of the county in acres? ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);

    printf("How much rainfall was recieved, in inches? ");
    scanf("%lf", &i);

    printf("What percent of the county recieved rainfall? ");
    scanf("%lf", &percent);


    g = convertGallons(cy);
    t = convertTonnes(lb);
    h = findHeight(cf);

    printf("%lf gallons fell in the county.\n", g);
    printf("The rainfall weighed %lf tonnes.\n", t);
    printf("The height of the football field is %lf miles.\n", h);

    return 0;
    }
```

When i try to compile this program i get the following errors:

```
project.c:67:3: warning: ‘cy’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
g = convertGallons(cy);
  ^
project.c:68:3: warning: ‘lb’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
t = convertTonnes(lb);
  ^
project.c:69:3: warning: ‘cf’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
h = findHeight(cf);
  ^
```

I'm sure there are plenty things wrong with this program (it's my first real program), and if you'd like I'd love to hear any additional inputs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As 'cy' is not defined in certain functions it will give error, try declaring it in the function or declare them Globally.

Comment: @Mayank please do not suggest global variables to someone still struggling with understanding variable scopes at all. It might appear as an easy fix-it-all-solution while leading to horribly buggy code. Of course, global variables have their valid use, but you should *really* understand what you're doing before using them.

Comment: Please indent the code before posting it here.

Comment: @FelixPalmen My comment was intended to give a way for sorting the issue not for misleading the questioner. Or in clear words i can say **Variables** must have to be declared before taking them in use .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is pretty descriptive in this case; you are using variables before initializing them which is not a good idea in C. e.g.

```
 g = convertGallons(cy);
```

`cy` is not initialized before it is used above. Use

```
double cy = 0; // Or some other initial value
```

during declaration (same for other variables). Reading values of uninitialized variables (and this is what happens when that variable is passed to the function - a copy of it is made, hence is is being *read* in a way) is undefined behaviour and seems compiler is complaining about that.

Comment: Or another way of putting it is *"How the heck is the compiler supposed to know the value of `cy` your are passing to `convertGallons` is??"*

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: yep, in this case I think compiler is only interested whether it was initialized or not

Comment: Yes, you were 100% correct, my comment was somewhat a *tongue-in-cheek* synopsis of the question posed and your answer.  It wasn't intended as a critique in any way... You know the old `int a, b;` then `int c = a + b;` Huh? Why doesn't that work...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I understand :). because of (un) initialization :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did what you said and initialized, and it compiled! All I need to do now is figure out why I'm getting 0.00000 for everything...

Comment: @TitustheTitan: This is because you are not using the values read from input. All your calculations operate on variables that are just 0.

Answer (score 0):

Because the variables are declared but not initialized to any value (They could contain any value). You may need to perform certain calculation to initialize them to certain values and then pass them to the functions.

i.e. `Amount of rainfall = area * inches of rainfall`, etc.

```
cy = a * (percent/100.0) * i ; 
/*calculates the volume of rainfall in acres * inches unit and provided you
  took percentage as 56% and not 0.56 (in which case, remove the division by 100.0)*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this part of the code:

```
printf("What is the size of the county in acres? ");
scanf("%lf", &a);

printf("How much rainfall was recieved, in inches? ");
scanf("%lf", &i);

printf("What percent of the county recieved rainfall? ");
scanf("%lf", &percent);


g = convertGallons(cy);
t = convertTonnes(lb);
h = findHeight(cf);
```

I *assume* you want to calculate based on the values entered. But this code assigns `a`, `i`, and `percent` a value, while feeding the uninitialized variables `cy`, `lb` and `cf` to your calculation functions.

So I assume further there is a *fundamental* misunderstanding about how variables work and what is their scope. The variables you declare inside a block (a pair of `{` and `}`) only exist inside this block. There can be other variables in the program with *the same name* in another block -- they are different and completely unrelated.

Especially, the arguments to a function are local variables, too, and only valid inside that function.

So, example from your code, the `cy` here:

```
double convertGallons(double cy)
{
    double g = cy / 201.974026;
    return g;
}
```

is a completely different variable than the `cy` here:

```
int main(void)
{

    double g, t, h, lb, i, cy, a, percent, cf;
```

`cy` in `main` needs to have a value if you want to do `convertGallons(cy)` - then the function call would assign the value of the `cy` in your `main()` to the `cy` in your `convertGallons()`. To better understand this, try giving these variables different names. But, of course, the same name is not an error, it's quite common in some cases.